# Function Hooking

Tags: c++, function, hook

I have a game which uses multiple dlls, some are core and some are custom, one of which is mine.

What I am trying to do, is to hook to an internal function from inside a core dll.
I can easily get the function's address:

```
HMODULE h_fct = GetModuleHandle("variables.dll");
char* ptr = (char*)h_fct + 0x10000;
MakeJMP((BYTE*)ptr, (DWORD)MyVariableCall, 5);
```

Then I can easily attach to it using a piece of code found on the internet, but I am not sure that this is right:

```
void MakeJMP(BYTE *pAddress, DWORD dwJumpTo, DWORD dwLen)
{
    DWORD dwOldProtect, dwBkup, dwRelAddr;
    VirtualProtect(pAddress, dwLen, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &dwOldProtect);  
    dwRelAddr = (DWORD) (dwJumpTo - (DWORD) pAddress) - 5;

    *pAddress = 0xE9;    
    *((DWORD *)(pAddress + 0x1)) = dwRelAddr;

    VirtualProtect(pAddress, dwLen, dwOldProtect, &dwBkup);    
    return;
}
```

Now here comes the kicker, my function

```
typedef int __cdecl func(int a1, int a2, signed int a3, double* a4, int a5);
char* ptr2;

int FSAPI MyVariableCall(int a1, int a2, int a3, double* a4, int a5)
{
    int a = 2;
    func* f = (func*)ptr2;
    a = f(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5);
    //I want code to reach here so I can call other function to modify the a4 pointer
    MyModifyingcode(a4);
    return a;
}
```

ptr2 is ptr + 0x5, this means that it moves past the 5 bytes. The first 5 bytes of the original dll are

```
mov     edi, edi
push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp

//Here is the prototype function from a disassembler:
signed int __userpurge sub_10AC0000<eax>(double result<st0>, double st6_0<st1>, double st5_0<st2>, double st4_0<st3>, double st3_0<st4>, double st2_0<st5>, int a2, signed int a3, int a4, double *a5, int a6)
```

My main desire is to run f(), meaning the original function, then to write my code.
So what i am trying to do is to hook to a function after it is being called.

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: You want a detour with a trampoline. Tricky to arrange. The Detours library can do it for you.

Comment: Can't I just modify the existing code that I have? Maybe add some asm instructions to preserve the stack?

Comment: Sure. That's the trampoline.

Comment: Can you please help me with a small example? Or where can I find some information that would pertain to my code?